# Wildcard or regex node express mount path on middleware

Tags: regex, node.js, express, wildcard, webhooks

I would like to define different middleware depending on how the path looks.
[image]

The thing is that the path may wary; I'd like to for instance support the following paths:

```
/chat/auth/test
/chat/auth/add
/chrome/auth/test
/chrome/add
```

Every time **auth** is in the path I would like the auth middleware to be called, and for **chat** and **chrome** I want their respective middlewares to be called.

app.js:

```
// Middleware authentication

var chatAuthenticate = require('./server/middleware/chat-authenticate');
app.use('/chat', chatAuthenticate(addon));

var authAuthentication = require('./server/middleware/auth-authenticate');
app.use('/auth', authAuthentication());
```

I understand that I can just add multiple entries to app.js for every possible combination, like /chat/auth and /chrome/auth and it wouldn't increase the complexity at all, but I'm just curious if it's possible to solve this with wildcards or regex :)

Comment: Every middleware gets called with `req, res, next`. So use `next` if you want to use another middleware, and don't use it if the middleware is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(/auth/, authAuthentication);
```

This will call authAuthentication for every request that contains `auth` anywhere. A few things to consider:

- It is a Regular Expression, so instead of quotes you just need /…/ as delimiters
- Note that if you have multiple middlewares that match a route (e.g. another one with `/chat/` as RegEx, and you call `/auth/chat` or `/chat/auth`, both middlewares will be called. Because of that it is important to consider the order of your `app.use()` calls.
- authAuthentication is required to expect `(request, response, next)` parameters. If you directly call the function as in your example, the function is expected to return a function that will take the three express middleware parameters.
- It is common practice to place all `require` calls at the top of your script
- Make sure you fully read and understood [Express Routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). It is awesome.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! authAuthentication does indeed return a function with said paramters. Thanks to the documentation you linked I figured out that you have to use app.all(): 

"There is a special routing method, app.all(), which is not derived from any HTTP method. This method is used for loading middleware functions at a path for all request methods."

EDIT: I'll edit your answer to app.all and accept it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards (at least in express 4):

```
app.use('/chat/*', chatMiddleware);
```

Which would apply that middleware first to any request starting with '/chat/'. Then use the next one for the next level which would only apply to '/chat/auth/*'...

```
app.use('/chat/auth/*', function(req, res, next) {
    //.... middleware logic here


    //.... assuming we don't reject the call, call next() when done
    next();
));
```